# What is the bug with these VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

My Task is I have to delete the entire Row if The K column Has zero value in it.First thing came to my mind is looping But i have 4000 rows and 1000 rows may have K value as zero.

```
Sub DeleteRowWithContents()
       Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
       For i = Last To 1 Step -1
           If (Cells(i, "K").Value) = 0 Then
              Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
           End If
       Next i
End Sub
```

I believe People say Its Time taking Process as it is looping. Thats why I thought better go for next methods and People also told me 'Find' is much faster than looping. So I have used the below code That I found when  I was googling

```
Sub Delete_zeros()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim strAddress As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    With ActiveSheet.Columns("K")
        Set rCell = .Find(What:=0, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
            Do
            strAddress = rCell.Address
            rCell.EntireRow.Delete
            Set rCell = .FindNext(Range(strAddress))
            Loop Until rCell Is Nothing
        End If
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But I found That the above code, it is also deleting the row if the k column has 10 or 20 Value in it. I mean if the Digit contains zero then its deleting

example .

```
    204 or 200 or 205 or 301 or 10 \ Its deleting all these rows
```

Whats wrong with these code? These code is too fast than looping I wanted to use but I found bug with it.

Please explain the reason to the bug. And any help to other method which is faster in deleting the rows if it has zero value in K column other than looping or (might be also looping should be too fast )? That would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not is bug, add this parameter in find method

LookAt:= xlwhole

To use filter do

```
Sub FilterAndDelete()
'Developer by Bruno Leite
'http://officevb.com 

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim FilterRange As Range
    
    'Set your Sheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan2")
    
    'Verify if is Filter
    If Sht.FilterMode Then
      Sht.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    'Filter Column A with 0 at parameter
    Sht.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
    
    'Define Range Of Visible cells without row title
    Set FilterRange = Sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
       
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    FilterRange.Rows.Delete
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
    Sht.ShowAllData
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Not is aint the bug i think because Its working even with not But thanks Bruno :)

Comment: Other way is use filter method and delete visible cells.

Comment: Do you think which is faster filter or Find? I belieave filter right?